# Payment options do not appear during onepage checkout

Tags: php, xml, magento, authorize.net

During the check out process once you get to step 4, Payment Information, nothing shows up. There's a continue button, but if you click it, you get pop up stating that "Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no payment methods available". I have no javascript errors at all. The AJAX calls done at this step are successful(200 response) according to firebug. I see nothing in the apache error logs. Before going live with this site we successfully completed test transactions. Once we went live we changed the domains, and applied SSL, now there is no way we can get past this step on the front end.  The only payment method we have enabled in the Magento config is Authorize.net.

Magento v1.4.2

https://www.time4health.com/shop-online

I am using Magebridge to handle the integration of a Magento store within Joomla; i have verified that it does not work via the Magento frontend either.

thank you in advice,

Comment: Have you tried going through the normal checkout process (not the One Page)?

Comment: When i disable onepage checkout, the button to check out disappears.  There is no way to check out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a magento payment extension that was installed(not by me) that needed a default method set.  Kind of ridiculous.

Sorry to waste everyones time

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you either don't have any payment methods enabled or your session (items in your basket / delivery address / billing address) somehow doesn't qualify for checkout.

I would suggest enabling one of the default payment modules. Purchase orders is always a safe bet.
"System" => "Configuration" => "payment methods"
Click "Purchase Orders" and then set "enabled" to "yes" and click save.

If this doesn't work. change the billing / shipping countries for your customers address to somewhere in America to see if the issue lies there.

Comment: Yes. You solved my problem. Customer address should belongs to the allowed country.